# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined on zTree_v3 library

Tags: javascript, jquery, ztree

I got problem with using zTree library. this is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url()?>asset/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url()?>asset/js/jquery.ztree.core-3.5.js"></script>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    var setting = {
        data: {
            simpleData: {
                enable: true
            }
        }
    };

    var zNodes =[
        { id:1, pId:0, name:"Custom Icon 01", open:true, iconOpen:"<?php echo base_url()?>asset/img/diy/1_open.png", iconClose:"<?php echo base_url()?>asset/img/diy/1_close.png"},
        { id:11, pId:1, name:"leaf node 01", icon:"<?php echo base_url()?>asset/img/diy/2.png"},
        { id:12, pId:1, name:"leaf node 02", icon:"<?php echo base_url()?>asset/img/diy/2.png"},
        { id:13, pId:1, name:"leaf node 03", icon:"<?php echo base_url()?>asset/img/diy/2.png"},
        { id:2, pId:0, name:"Custom Icon 02", open:true, iconOpen:"<?php echo base_url()?>asset/img/diy/1_open.png", iconClose:"<?php echo base_url()?>asset/img/diy/1_close.png"},
        { id:21, pId:2, name:"leaf node 01", icon:"<?php echo base_url()?>asset/img/diy/8.png"},
        { id:22, pId:2, name:"leaf node 02", icon:"<?php echo base_url()?>asset/img/diy/8.png"},
        { id:23, pId:2, name:"leaf node 03", icon:"<?php echo base_url()?>asset/img/diy/8.png"}

    ];

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.fn.zTree.init($("#treeDemo"), setting, zNodes);
    });
    //-->
</SCRIPT>
```

and I get some error like

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined
>   (anonymous function)
>   b.extend.ready
>   u

please help me, how can I resolve this problem? thanks

Answer (score 5):

This happens because of including js at multiple places. I have encountered the same issue in my Portal page where jquery-1.4.4.min.js and jquery.ztree.core-3.5.js were included many places.

I fixed this issue by removing all references to js from all the portlets on that page and added these js globally in theme/_diff/portal_noraml.vm in the given order.

Answer (score 0):

This error's in your `$(document).ready()`, and it's because your zTree script hasn't been loaded correctly. "Cannot read property 'init' of undefined" means you wrote something that evaluates as `undefined.init` - so you know that `$.fn.zTree` is undefined.

If you check the network tab of your browser's developer tools, you should hopefully see the problem. I'd guess it'll either be a 404 (ie. the `src` attribute of the `<script>` tag is incorrect) or a 403 (ie. you need to change the permissions on your zTree file so the web server can read it).

Comment: how to change the permission?

Comment: You'll have to log in to your web server and use [chmod](http://www.zzee.com/solutions/how-to-use-chmod.shtml#zzee_link_1_1077830225) on the file.