# jQuery Datatable DOM positioning for Buttons

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, datatables-1.10

I just upgraded my jQuery Datatable version to 1.10. And then i tried to remove its retired plugin such as "Colvis" and "Tabletools" with the "Button" extension. Everything works fine here.

But the problem for me is, I could not able to separate "Colvis" button from the "Tabletool" buttons.

```
"sDom": "B<'row'><'row'<'col-md-6'l><'col-md-6'f>r>t<'row'<'col-md-4'i>><'row'p>B",
    "buttons": [
        'copyHtml5',
        'excelHtml5',
        'csvHtml5',     
        {
            extend: 'colvis',
            postfixButtons: [ 'colvisRestore' ],
            columns: '0,1,2,3,4,5,6'
        }
    ],
    language: {
        buttons: {
            colvis: 'Change columns'
        }
    }
```

Where in the "sDom", the letter "B" denotes for Buttons. So i am getting all four Buttons (Copy, Excel, CSV and Colvis) in a single row. But i need the "Colvis" button to be separated from (Copy, Excel and CSV).

So Is there any way to add one button near to search box and another one near to the pagination?

OR

Is there any configuration available in the "sDom" or in the "Button"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You add new elements to the dataTables dom controls by using `<'.class'>` or `<'#id'>`. Example, insert a new `<div id="colvis">` element to the left of the pagination, `<'#colvis'>` before `p` :

```
"sDom": "B<'row'><'row'<'col-md-6'l><'col-md-6'f>r>t<'row'<'col-md-4'i>><'row'<'#colvis'>p>"
```

colvis buttons has the class `.buttons-colvis`, so you move them permanently to the injected `#colvis` element by :

```
$('.buttons-colvis').detach().appendTo('#colvis')
```

This is the fast way to move the colvis button to another location.

---

Regarding @GreeKatrina's suggestion, yes - but the correct placement method is :

```
var colvis = new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons( table, {
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'colvis',
            ... 
        }
   ]
})
colvis.container().appendTo('#colvis')
```

*if* you have a `#colvis` element of course.

---

**My recommendation :**
Besides the above hardcoded solution, where you target the colvis buttons specifically, you could monkey patch dataTables buttons so *each* extended button can have a `container` option. After initialisation, the button is moved to the specified `container` :

```
var org_buildButton = $.fn.DataTable.Buttons.prototype._buildButton;
$.fn.DataTable.Buttons.prototype._buildButton = function(config, collectionButton) {
   var button = org_buildButton.apply(this, arguments);
   $(document).one('init.dt', function(e, settings, json) {
       if (config.container && $(config.container).length) {
          $(button.inserter[0]).detach().appendTo(config.container)
       }
   })    
   return button;
}
```

use the `container` option :

```
{
   extend: 'colvis',
   postfixButtons: [ 'colvisRestore' ],
   container : '#colvis', //<---
   columns: '0,1,2,3,4,5'
}
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/v4bLv83h/**

As the example demonstrates, you can now specify an alternative container for each and every button. Note that `container` can be any element, it does not have to be an element injected by `dom`. Also note (as you may notice in the fiddle) that you need to do some styling if you want to make injected elements flow properly along with the native control elements, such as the pagination block.

Comment: This is the exact solution i was looking for, works great, thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an expert with the data tables library, but the [documentation](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/#In-DataTables) says you can have multiple collections of buttons and insert them separately. It also has an example for [multiple button groups](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/multiple.html) that you could use instead of putting "B" multiple times in the `dom` option, which I don't think is valid.

Combining the examples from the documentation and your example (not tested):

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable( {
    dom: "B<'#colvis row'><'row'><'row'<'col-md-6'l><'col-md-6'f>r>t<'row'<'col-md-4'i>><'row'p>",
    buttons: [
        'copyHtml5',
        'excelHtml5',
        'csvHtml5'
    ]
} );

new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons( table, {
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'colvis',
            // Shorter than using the language.buttons.colvis option
            text: 'Change columns',
            postfixButtons: [ 'colvisRestore' ],
            columns: '0,1,2,3,4,5,6'
        }
    ]
} );

// To append it at the bottom of the table
// 3 since the colvis button is at the 3rd index in the buttons array
table.buttons( 3, null ).container().appendTo(
    table.table().container()
);

// To append it on the first row after the buttons, in the #colvis row
table.buttons( 3, null ).container().appendTo(
     $('#colvis'), table.table().container()
);
```

If it doesn't work let me know and I'll update my answer.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for you reply. But it is throwing an error like "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'inst' of undefined" from the Datatable JS  file.

Comment: Mutilple `B`'s is perfectly legal. dataTables just inserts a "cloned" button section for each `B`.  Yes, declaring multiple button objects could be a workaround, a more complex version of just moving the buttons. However, it should be `<buttonObject>.container().appendTo(<element>)`, and  `table.table().container()` is just the table wrapper itself.

Comment: @Yadheendran I'm guessing you are getting that error because you are not loading the library correctly. `$.fn.dataTable` is probably undefined and throwing that error. I would have to see how you're loading the scripts to be sure. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24605791/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-init-of-undefined-on-ztree-v3-library) and both answers.