# How to display datatable button separate from button group?

Tags: jquery, button, datatables

I have a row of buttons at the bottom of a [DataTable](https://datatables.net/) like this below. But now I want to add a separate button `colVis` to the top of the table.

Following [this example](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/multiple.html) I've tried the following specifying the new button to be placed at `dom: 'Bfrtip'` but I get the error - `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tag' of undefined at new m (dataTables.buttons.min.js:6)`

**Question:**

How can you display datatable button separate from button group?

```
var historyTable = $('#escalation').DataTable({
        "order": [[10, "desc"]],
        colReorder: true,
        columnDefs: [
        {
            orderable: false,
            targets: [7, 11, 12, 13, 14]
        },
        {
            "width": "15%",
            "targets": [7, 11]
        }
        ],
        responsive: true,
        buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'pdf',
            footer: true,
            exportOptions: {
                columns: [1, 2, 5, 6, 11]
            }
        },
        {
            extend: 'print',
            footer: true,
            exportOptions: {
                columns: [1, 2, 5, 6, 11]
            }
        },
        'copy', 'csv', 'excel'
        ],
        'iDisplayLength': 55,
    });


    new $.fn.DataTable.Buttons(historyTable, {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'colvis'

            },   
        ]
    });

    historyTable.buttons(1, null).container().appendTo(
    historyTable.table().container()
);
```

I also tried the following creating a new button for `colVis` and appending to a div with id colFilter at the top of the table to no avail:

```
//Place colVis filter button at top of table
    var colvis = new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons(historyTable, {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'colvis'
            }
    ]
    });

    colvis.container().appendTo('#colFilter');
```

And in a third attempt tried this approach explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34416766/jquery-datatable-dom-positioning-for-buttons):

```
    //Place colVis filter button at top of table
    var colvis = new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons(historyTable, {
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'colvis',
                postfixButtons: ['colvisRestore']
            }
    ]
    });

    historyTable.buttons(3, null).container().appendTo('#colFilter');
```

Example like this:

[image]

Comment: this is a more robust solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34577139/3393929

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me.  It puts one button at the bottom and one at the top. I have tested the button functionality with no issues but did not test accessing the button container object via DataTable so there may be side effects.

you can see it work at https://jsfiddle.net/bindrid/sc0bo122/11/

```
$("#example").one("preInit.dt", function (evtObj, settings){

    var $newbtncontainer = $("<div class='dt-buttons'></div>");
    $("#example_wrapper").prepend($newbtncontainer);
    $("a.buttons-colvis").appendTo($newbtncontainer);
});
```

Comment: I notice adding `dom: 'ftBip',` removes my dropdown to filter number of row results per page. Any idea why that is?

Comment: I think you need to add "l" for length control. Keep in mind if you put that as 'lftBip', my code would put the button before the dropdown. If you don't like that, you would need to change the code to     $("#example_length").after(

Comment: also, the 'dt-buttons' class just basically adds a float left.  In my code where I am doing something similar, I just added style='float:right: instead of using the class.

Answer (score 0):

Some simple Idea is, to remove class "btn-group" after render with jquery. To be save, this has to be done on hook of the render event of DT.