# jQuery Datatable How push export button to right and leave lengthMenu in left?

Tags: jquery, html, datatable

Datatable Script:

```
var tblPreventivi  = $('#example').DataTable({
         "order": [[ 5, "desc" ]],
         "dom": 'lBfrtip',
        "buttons": [
        { 
            extend:'excel',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: [ 0,2,3,4,5 ]
            }
        },
        { 
            extend:'pdf',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: [ 0,2,3,4,5 ]
            }
        },
        ],
        "lengthMenu": [[20, 50, 100, -1], [20, 50, 100, "All"]]
    });
```

i am getting below screenshot:
[image: my screen preview]

so i need for `DataTable options`

anyone please Help me out!

i need below screenshot:
[image: need final output]

Comment: This may help you out [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34416766/jquery-datatable-dom-positioning-for-buttons/34577139#34577139)