# Progress bar animation when inputing form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, progress-bar

I want to make when my form is filled by someone, the progress bar width increase by 20.

```
   <form  action="class/action.php" method="post">
     <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="form-group label-floating">
            <label class="control-label">Name </label>
            <input id="1" type="text" class="form-control pgbar" name="name" required>
        </div>
    </div>
   </form>

   <!-- Progress bar -->
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-6">
                 <div class="progress progress-line-primary ">
                     <div class="progress-bar" id="progressbar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 1%;"> </div>
                  </div>
             </div>
          </div>
      </div>

  //javascript      
$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
      value: 0
    });

$(".pgbar").change(function() {
    var pbVal = 0;
    if ($("#1").val().length > 0) pbVal += 20;
    if ($("#2").val().length > 0) pbVal += 20;
    if ($("#3").val().length > 0) pbVal += 20;
    if ($("#4").val().length > 0) pbVal += 20;
    if ($("#5").val().length > 0) pbVal += 20;
    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar( "option", "value", pbVal );
    return false;
});
```

i am not sure its wrong with my html or javascript. Thanks for help, appreciate it.

Comment: Is there an error?

Comment: Looks like you are resetting pbVal to 0 each time 'change' is fired. put it outside the block.

Comment: yes the progress ar width keep 1%

Comment: @GeorgeCampbell i have tried to do that but its nothing happen with my progress bar.

Comment: @GeorgeCampbell yes it's reset to 0 and then *immediately* fully recalculated based on the 5 values

Comment: What happens if you load the page then open the console and enter `$( "$("#progressbar").progressbar( "option", "value", 50 );` ?

Comment: Placing your code into a snippet with the required references works fine (Increase the 1% width to see it working). What errors do you get? P.s: Apologies for the temporary Edit, I didn't realize I edited the question and accidentally saved - I reverted the edit again

Comment: `style="width: 1%;"` will make it a very small progress bar - are you sure it's not actually working but you just can't see it?  (I'm not 100% sure how the jquery-ui progress bar works, but this doesn't seem right)

Comment: Seeing your code works, I assume you are missing a reference or trying to attach the change event before the DOM is ready. Might need a `$(document).ready(funciton(){... your code here ...})`

Comment: there are no html elements with id 2,3,4,5

Comment: You've not stated what the problem actually is.

Comment: @GeorgeCampbell yes cause im not copying all of my input form

Comment: @Even can you describe what it does/doesn't do that you're expecting it to do?

Comment: its not working in my web, I dont know how its working in yours. And I'm still trying too, so sorry for slow response

Comment: Maybe I was being a bit harsh - but we still don't know the symptoms of it not working.  Does @GeorgeCampbell 's snippet work for you?  Can you check for errors in the browser console (press F12 and select console then refresh your page ) - copy any messages from there to this question

Comment: yes, I know my problem now. It's error cause I'm not increase the width of my progress bar. I think 'code progressbar( "option", "value", pbVal );' didn't work in my web. Thank you for response @freedomn-m

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm unsure of the issue because I cannot see a working example. Here is a working solution.

```js
$("#progressbar").progressbar({
  value: 0
});
var $inputs = $(".form-group").children("input");
var totalInputs = $inputs.length;

  $inputs.on('keyup', function() {
    var pbVal = 0;
    $inputs.each(function(){
      if($(this).val().length > 0) pbVal ++;
    });

    $("#progressbar").progressbar("option", "value", (pbVal/totalInputs)*100)
  });
```

```css
.container{
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form action="class/action.php" method="post">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group label-floating">
      <label class="control-label">1</label>
      <input id="input-1" type="text" class="form-control pgbar" name="name" required>
      <label class="control-label">2</label>
      <input id="input-2" type="text" class="form-control pgbar" name="name" required>
      <label class="control-label">3</label>
      <input id="input-3" type="text" class="form-control pgbar" name="name" required>
      <label class="control-label">4</label>
      <input id="input-4" type="text" class="form-control pgbar" name="name" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<!-- Progress bar -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-6">
      <div class="progress progress-line-primary ">
        <div class="progress-bar" id="progressbar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `pbVal` *outside* the change function doesn't work - it will never get reset.  did you try your code?  every keypress increases by 20% even if input is cleared.  OP has 5 inputs with 20% for each input

Comment: actually a better solution is to use a percentage, not just add 20 each time. .width(totalWidth/changedInputs)

Comment: If max = 100 then adding 20 is the same as calculating `100/5` each time...

Comment: it's work thanks, the problem is I'm not increase my width with pbVal

Comment: @Evan This will not work properly because `pvVal` must be reset each time. See my answer below.

Comment: The problem is that you set/change the width at all (as my earlier comment on the question) - use the progress bar as it's designed by setting the width to 100% and changing the *value*

Comment: Don't know why this was marked as the correct answer. It's not.

Comment: No, you haven't.

Comment: You're looping through all the inputs to give each a `keyup` event handler (not necessary and wasteful) *and* in the keyup, you're looping through all the inputs again. Not to mention that your answer fixes the biggest problem with the original code, but never mentions what that is as well as it still saying that `pbVal` should ***not*** be reset.

Comment: theres nothing wrong with looping within the keyup or, and using keyup event is more user friendly. its 5 inputs, not 5000.

Comment: I misunderstood the question initially and understand pbVal should be reset

Comment: About `keyup`: It's not necessary and there very well could be 5000 keyup events in just 5 inputs (also, more inputs could be added later adding to the `keyup` count). And, what if the user types in the field and then undoes their changes? That's a ton of work for nothing. On `pbVal` being reset. Yes, you corrected your code, but not the text of your answer. Lastly, your code fixes the actual main problem, but you never mentioned what that was.

Comment: well he can just make it 'change' isntead of 'keyup', just depends if he wants the pb to update straight away or after blurring the input

Comment: Lastly, your code fixes the actual main problem, but you never mentioned what that was.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, you've included the theme CSS file so that you can see your progress bar in the first place (code below).

**And, speaking of style, your `style` is set to `1%` by default. Even when it works, you'll never see it. The `width` doesn't have to be `100%`, but it has to be big enough to see.**

Next, it's easier to keep a count of the non-empty elements, not necessarily the final progress bar value because if you add responses or remove responses later, your math will be wrong.

Then you just divide the number of non-empty fields by the amount of fields and set that as the `value`. You were setting `value` as an `option`, but according to the **[docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/)**, that's not how to do it:

> ```
> ( ".selector" ).progressbar( "value", 50 );
> ```

Also, it's simpler (and more scalable) to just loop through each of the fields and check their `val()` for non-empty than to test each one individually.

---

Here's an example with the non-relevant stuff taken out:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 0  });
  
  // Apply the styling that is defined in the linked CSS stylesheet
  $("#progressbar").progressbar( "option", "classes.ui-progressbar", "highlight" );
});

// Us the ".on()" method instead of "change" as recommended by jQuery
$("input").on("change", function() {
  var count = 0;  // We won't be storing a final value, just a count of non-empty fields
  
  // Loop through the fields (better than testing one-by-one)
  $("input").each(function(idx, input){
    // Test the value for non-empty and increase the count if empty
    if($(input).val() !== "") { count++ };
  }); 
  
  // Now you can calculate the whole number representation of the % of completed fields
  var pbVal = (count / $("input").length) * 100;
  
  // Set the progress bar to the value
  $("#progressbar").progressbar("value", pbVal);
  
  // EXTRA CREDIT: When the progress = 100%, enable the submit button
  $("button").prop("disabled", pbVal !== 100);
});
```

```css
input { display: block; }
#progressbar { display:inline-block; width:75%; border-radius:25px; }
div { margin:1em 0;  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!-- Make sure you have the CSS linked to for visibility and styling -->
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- **************************************************************************** -->

<form  action="class/action.php" method="post">
  <input id="1">
  <input id="2">
  <input id="3">
  <input id="4">
  <input id="5">            
</form>

<!-- Progress bar -->
<div>0%<span id="progressbar"></span>100%</div>
<button disabled>Submit</button>
```

Comment: A quick test in your snippet (didn't meant to save, hopefully rolledback your edit) shows that `.progressbar("option", "value", value)` does also work:  `$("#progressbar").progressbar("option", "value", (count / $("input").length) * 100);`

Comment: i use material kit and your code doesn't work. Maybe I just can change the width. But thank you I have tried in your snippets and its work fine

Comment: @Evan I don't know what "material kit" is, but that should not have any impact on this code. Most likely, you've got another issue that is preventing this code from running. Check your developer's console (F12) to see if there are errors.

Comment: material-kit.js:27 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined

Comment: @Evan Yup. That's a completely different issue than the code we're talking about here. Look at what you've typed right before `.init`. The error means that whatever that is, it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Evan This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24605791/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-init-of-undefined-on-ztree-v3-library

Comment: @Evan If you've already got jQuery and jQuery UI referenced in your code, don't copy those lines from my code snippet.

Comment: its nothing, I just use theme for my css, maybe you can try it's too with this theme [link](https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design#materialjs)

Comment: I'm not talking about the CSS. I'm talking about the `script` references. I don't know anything about material.js, so I really can't help you there other than to advise you like the link I supplied not to reference jQuery and jQuery UI more than once.